# Star Wars - Jedi philosophy in combat

Tags: star-wars, jedi

As mentioned in this SFF question:

[How was Obi-Wan felled by such minor injuries?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/28818/star-wars-attack-of-the-clones-obi-wan-and-dooku)

Count Dooku had superior fighting skills with the light saber than Obi-Wan, and Obi-Wan knows it and probably knew it before hand as Count Dooku was known to have wide fighting skills.

In that situation, when a Jedi knows his opponent is superior to him, is he allowed/supposed to just flee?? Obviously in the movies it wouldn't make for an appealing scene and its better to show the character die (or almost)... But is there any canon reference where a Jedi has run for his life?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes. G-canon, in fact :)

Luke Skywalker's jump out of Cloud City onto the spire was just that.

Obi-Wan and Qui-Gon in Episode I ran (or rather swam) for their life from a big fish.

Jedi were NOT Samurai, and the part of Bushido about death being the only defeat option was not in the least part of the Jedi Code, despite some similarities.

However, Jedi were also supremely devoted to their duty, and ready to risk their lives to fulfill their duty/objective if there was no other choice.